# Can I short a stock in UK using a shares ISA?

Tags: united-kingdom, shorting-securities, isa

If not please advise on other straight forward method (hoping I don't have to open a complicated account for this). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but I will question the reason behind this. And I cannot guarantee if all ISA providers, including yours, will allow you to short.

Better get a [CFD account](http://www.money.co.uk/cfds.htm) and run wild.

In the end, I will still question why you want to short, seeing that you aren't sure if your ISA provider can allow you to short. And on top of it you want to use your ISA to short shares. I don't believe they allow you margin trading. Some CFD account providers give you a test trading account, use it before you take the big jump.

Comment: Can you give an example of an ISA provider that allows this?

Comment: Yes, please I need an example too. I already short using a margin account but I get taxed on my gains.

Answer (score 0):

Profits for ISAs are tax free, profits from CFD accounts are subject to capital gains. I don't know of a single ISA provider that allows you to short individual stocks